# Passing Data from Coldfusion to Flex

Tags: apache-flex, coldfusion, argument-passing

I'm working on a flex app which is to be embedded in a Coldfusion page and am wondering what the best way is to pass data from the coldfusion page into the flex app. The app really just represents a module in the Coldfusion application. I normally just use remote object calls and the creationComplete method in Flex to instantiate any variables and methods I want to run at start.

Since flex doesn't represent the entire app, I was wondering if there is a better way aside from creationComplete to pass a coldfusion variable into flex when the use clicks on the link to the flex app.